# Grados de formalidad en las expresiones para ir al baño

Tags: uso-de-palabras, formalidad

En español para decir que alguien ha ido al cuarto de baño, podemos elegir entre [váter](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bPZCCo5), [aseo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3xrkt7K), [baño](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4z67B1J), [escusado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GOBfMu0)... y seguramente algunas más que no recuerdo o que desconozco.

Sin embargo, en mi caso al menos (España), algunas de esas palabras se corresponden a distintos niveles de formalidad en el habla. Por ejemplo:

- hablando con mi familia **en mi casa**, no tengo problema en decirle que vaya al **váter**;
- si **en la oficina** me preguntan por un compañero que ha ido a tal, diría que ha ido al **aseo** o al **baño**, nunca al váter;
- en el caso de estar hablando con **alguien desconocido** de quien ignoro su nivel de sensibilidad ante este tipo de palabras, posiblemente escogería **escusado** (o **excusado**), aunque lo cierto es que apenas la he usado nunca.

¿Es correcta mi apreciación? Y en tal caso, ¿el criterio es el mismo en todas las regiones de habla hispana? Y ya puestos, ¿hay alguna guía sobre cuándo usar un término u otro?

Comment: ¿E _ir al servicio_ no lo utilizas? Yo lo asocio con el tercer nivel, el relativo a alguien desconocido.

Comment: Para mi "ir al baño" vale para todas las situaciones, es la palabra que suelo usar yo. Aseo, excusado, servicio, retrete... son palabras que no uso jamás, casi siempre *baño* o *váter*, esta última es más coloquial.

Comment: Creo que jamás he dicho ni diré "excusado". Si no tengo confianza con la persona a lo mejor diría "tengo que ausentarme un momento" sin dar más explicaciones. Si me siento con ganas de risa igual diría "tengo que ir a hacer algo que nadie puede hacer por mí". :-D

Comment: Propongo que reestructures esta página, pasando tus cuatro términos a una respuesta comunitaria.  La mayor parte de la respuesta de Pablo podría ser un prólogo.  Se puede hacer una lista ya sea de términos y luego la gente agrega ahí su país si es que ese término se utiliza ahí; o bien una lista de países, tal y como se ha hecho varias veces.

Comment: @walen - Ah, bueno. // Podrias identificar tu pais o region en la pregunta, porfa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La variedad de maneras en que nos referimos a la susodicha habitación y, por metonimia, al acto que realizamos en ella, es impresionante en el mundo hispanoparlante. Que se los llama *aseos* en España es algo que descubrí recientemente. En Perú se los marca con las letras *SS.HH.*, que luego de larga investigación descubrí que significa *servicios higiénicos*. En Argentina se denominan *sanitarios*.

Estas palabras son formales y por mi parte jamás las he escuchado, sólo leído en la señalización de los baños en bares, tiendas de departamentos, aeropuertos, etc. En el caso de *sanitarios*, en Argentina ni siquiera se usa en el registro formal; casi siempre se habla, por ejemplo, de *baños públicos*, salvo en comunicaciones oficiales.

Nuestra conocida informalidad hace que no empleemos casi nunca otra expresión que la muy llana *ir al baño*. Cuando uno está en casa de alguien más puede decir *«Voy a pasar al baño»*, en vez de *ir*; si no sabe dónde es, puede preguntar *«¿Dónde está el baño?»*, aunque es algo más cortés aludir a la necesidad: *«Tendría que pasar al baño...»*. En la oficina donde trabajo, rodeado de almas delicadas, hay quien avisa de manera directa **qué es lo que va a hacer** al baño, utilizando los verbos castizos bien conocidos por todos nosotros.

Creo que quien conoce la palabra *excusado* como "baño" hoy en Argentina lo hace gracias a haber visto [El Chavo del Ocho](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Chavo_del_8)...

Comment: Los _servicios higiénicos_ peruanos también valen para Chile.