# ¿Es universal la distincion entre "del uno" y "del dos"?

Tags: vocabulario

En México cuando **se hace del uno**, se trata de orinar, cuando **se hace del dos,** es lo otro.  ¿Estas expresiones funcionan en tu país/región?

Comment: Es la primera vez que oigo esas expresiones. Aquí diría, de memoria, que lo más cercano podría ser **aguas menores** y **aguas mayores**. Pero no sé, algo me dice que podríamos tener alguna expresión más parecida.

Comment: @Charlie - gracias por los edits.  // Es decir, cuando estas en la biblioteca con un ni~no peque~no, como preguntas si quiere hacer pip'i?  Hay un eufemismo para esto en Espa~na?

Comment: Sin eufemismos. Cuando nuestro hijo tiene pipí o caca, esas son las palabras exactas que usamos. Aquí son palabras que se consideran infantiles y no necesitan más eufemismos. Curiosamente, el otro día leí en el diccionario de Covarrubias que ya en 1611 los niños usaban la palabra "caca" para indicar que tenían que ir al baño.

Comment: @Charlie - Bien, pero ¿qué vas a hacer cuando tu hijo esté un poco más grande?  Por ejemplo, si están en la biblioteca y le tienes que preguntar. 
 A cierta edad tanto los papás como el hijo empiezan a apreciar los eufemismos, en público. / Pero por mí, bien puedes seguir con pipí y caca. Mejor te pregunto: en tu entorno, la gente que se siente más cómoda con eufemismos, ¿qué dicen?

Comment: Pues entonces usaríamos alguna expresión tipo "ir al baño", como se indicó en [esta otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24066/12637), sin especificar el tipo de urgencia, o como mucho decir si es pipí o lo otro.

Comment: Puede que esto sea influencia de los estadounidenses ya que ahí se utilizan estos eufemismos y puede que hayan influenciado a México (y Guatemala)

Comment: @Charlie - ¿Se entenderían estos eufemismos donde tú?

Answer (score 2):

What follows is based on what was discussed in [Let's use community wiki to summarize a set of short region-specific answers](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2483/1674). Feel free to edit to add the term used in your country or region.

#### Sí. Estas expresiones funcionan así también en:

- Guatemala. Las expresiones se usan de la misma forma. La frecuencia en la que se usan puede variar con la de México.

#### No. Estas expresiones no funcionan así en las siguientes áreas, donde más bien se usan estas otras:

- España. No se usan eufemismos, por ejemplo los niños piden ir al baño con "pipí" o "caca" directamente. Las expresiones "aguas menores" y "aguas mayores" suenan ya muy caducas. Como mucho, la palabra "caca" que es algo escatológica, se cambia por "popó" o por "lo otro".